# Trying to create a new text file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, io

I am trying to create a new file and write to it in Flutter and I get an error that states:
*[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/data/user/0/com.micharski.d_ball/app_flutter/levels/level101.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)*

Here is my code (I am using the path_provider plugin):

```dart
class LevelFactory {
  Level level;
  File levelFile;

  Future<File> _createLevelFile() async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    File file = File('levels/level101.json');
    return file.create();
  }

  Future<void> createLevel() async {
    if(level != null){
      level = null;
    }
    levelFile = await _createLevelFile();
    print(levelFile);
  }
}
```

Inside the driver class:

```dart
var customLvl = new LevelFactory();
customLvl.createLevel();
```

For debugging purposes, I added this to _createLevelFile():

```dart
    Directory dir2 = Directory('$appDocPath/levels');
    print('DIR2 PATH: ${dir2.absolute}');
```

My output is now this:

```
I/flutter ( 7990): DIR2 PATH: Directory: '/data/user/0/com.micharski.d_ball/app_flutter/levels'
E/flutter ( 7990): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/data/user/0/com.micharski.d_ball/app_flutter/levels/level101.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File paths in Flutter can't be relative. The mobile operating system will interpret paths like `"levels/level101.json"` as either an invalid path or a path to a location that your app doesn't have permission to access. You need to use a plugin like [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get the path to your app's local data folder and then build absolute paths from that.

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> _createLevelFile() async {
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
  File file = File('$appDocPath/levels/level101.json');
  return await file.create();
}
```

Comment: I still get the same exception.

Comment: @amicharski Does the `levels` directory exist? If not, you'll need to create that first.

Comment: Yes, and I made changes to the question because I made some adjustments to my code.

Comment: @amicharski Have you actually created the directory? The code you added to your question doesn't create the directory, only a `Directory` object. You need to call `Directory.create` to create the directory itself.

Comment: the /levels/ directory was created manually in the file system interface.

Answer (score 0):

just use this

File file = await File('your/path/to/save/Filename.extension');

file.create(recursive: true);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).